# Flex box stacking

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive

I am working on one website, where in I have created column-layout for design.
I want the  responsive column layout with three columns in a large screen,
then two-column and in smaller screen single column.
I tried flex-wrap, also tried flex-direction and width ratio, but none was found useful !!!!!

Can anyone help me out with this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e5e5dc, #D4DCF0, #D8D4F0, #DAD4F0);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
} 


/** HEADER **/
#header-nav {
  background-color: #4d5198;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.navbar-brand h1 { 
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: .75;
}

.navbar-brand a:hover, .navbar-brand a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#nav-list a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#nav-list a:hover {
  background: #E7E7E7;
  color: #222;
}

#nav-list a i {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle, .navbar-header .icon-bar {
  border: 1px solid#fff;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
/* END HEADER */








/***div class info ***/

.diskinfo {
  display: grid;
}

.diskinfo p.hd {
  color: #2E4053;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #4d5198;
}

#diskimg {
  height: 20%;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px 30px 0;
}

#diskimg2 {
  height: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 30px 30px;
}

#intro, #terms, #hd2, #why{
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: #546C85;
}

#intro {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#terms {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#bold {
  font-size: 21px;
}

#why {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.cont{
  display : inline-flexbox;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row{
  display : flex;
  padding: 25px;
  
}
.col-sm{
  margin: 1.5%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px  rgb(100, 103, 139);
  text-align: center;
  padding:2%;
  width: 50%;
  color:rgba(14, 14, 100, 0.966);
  background-color: #fff;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.description{
  color: rgba(14, 14, 100, 0.966);
  font-size: large;
  text-align: justify;
}







/* MEDIA QUERIES */

/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-sm{
    width: 33%;
  }
  
  
}

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #intro, #hd2, #why {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  #terms {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  #bold {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .col-sm{
    width: 50%;
  }

}

/********** Small devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-brand h1 { 
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 4.5vw; 
  }

  .diskinfo p.hd {
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }

  #diskimg {
    height: 25%;
    width: 35%;
  }

  #diskimg2 {
    height: 35%;
    width: 45%;
  }

  #intro, #hd2, #why {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  #terms {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  #bold {
    font-size: 17px;
  }

}


/********** Extra small devices only **********/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Header */
  .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .navbar-brand h1 { 
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 5vw; /* 1vw = 1% of viewport width */
  }

  #collapsable-nav a { /* Collapsed nav menu text */
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  #collapsable-nav a i { /* Collapsed nav menu glyph */
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .diskinfo p.hd {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  #diskimg {
    height: 35% ;
    width: 45%;
  }

  #diskimg2 {
    height: 45% ;
    width: 55%;
  }

  #intro, #hd2, #why {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  #terms {
    font-size: 13px;;
  }

  #bold {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Disk Scheduling Algorithms</title>
    
    <!--CSS and Script linking-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    
  </head>

  <body>
        <div class="cont">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <h2>First Come First Serve (FCFS)</h2>
            <p class="description">FCFS is the simplest disk scheduling algorithm. As the name suggests, this algorithm entertains requests in the order they arrive in the disk queue. The algorithm looks very fair and there is no starvation (all requests are serviced sequentially) but generally, it does not provide the fastest service.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <h2>Shortest Seek Time First (SSTF)</h2> 
            <p class="description">Shortest seek time first (SSTF) algorithm selects the disk I/O request which requires the least disk arm movement from its current position regardless of the direction. It reduces the total seek time as compared to FCFS. It allows the head to move to the closest track in the service queue.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <h2>SCAN<br><br></h2>
            <p class="description">In SCAN disk scheduling algorithm, head starts from one end of the disk and moves towards the other end, servicing requests in between one by one and reach the other end. Then the direction of the head is reversed and the process continues as head continuously scan back and forth to access the disk.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <h2>Circular SCAN (C-SCAN)<br><br></h2>
              <p class="description">Circular SCAN (C-SCAN) scheduling algorithm is a modified version of SCAN disk scheduling algorithm that deals with the inefficiency of SCAN algorithm by servicing the requests more uniformly. Like SCAN (Elevator Algorithm) C-SCAN moves the head from one end servicing all the requests to the other end.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <h2>LOOK<br><br></h2>
              <p class="description">The LOOK algorithm services request similarly as SCAN algorithm meanwhile it also “looks” ahead as if there are more tracks that are needed to be serviced in the same direction. If there are no pending requests in the moving direction the head reverses the direction and start servicing requests in the opposite direction. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <h2>Circular LOOK<br><br></h2>
              <p class="description">In this algorithm, the head services requests only in one direction until all the requests in this direction are not serviced and then jumps back to the farthest request on the other direction and service the remaining requests which gives a better uniform servicing as well as avoids wasting seek time for going till the end of the disk.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      


    </div>


    
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do it is use a grid. Flex boxes work great if you have a single line of stuff and you want to control it either vertically or horizontally (and automate wrapping to a new line), but as soon as you want to control both dimensions, a grid is easier to use.

With a grid, all you have to do is change the `grid-template-columns` value in your different media queries to get different numbers of columns. Here's a simple example:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
}

.container div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
    <div>Six</div>
  </div>
```

The `1fr` means one fraction of the available width. So, `repeat(3, 1fr)` is equivalent to `1fr 1fr 1fr`, which would divide the available width into three equal fractions. The `gap` value sets vertical and horizontal gutters.

All you really need to set up a grid display is a container with `display: grid` set on it, a `grid-template-columns` value (if you want anything other than the default value of `1fr`), a set of items in the container, and an understanding that the grid is applied to *all* of the *immediate* children of the container and any deeper content is ignored. There's a lot more you can do with grids, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much easy and useful

Comment: @MalviPatel You're welcome. (Maybe you can upvote the post, too, if you think it will help other people.) It's a good idea to know both flex and grid, and when to use them. People have a way of learning flex, trying to use it for everything, then learning grid when they find something that flex doesn't work well for and using it for everything instead. Basically, use flex for a line (or lines) of items, and grid for a rectangle of items.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap? I see in your HTML you are linking to a bootstrap stylesheet.

If you are using bootstrap, you are not using the correct classes on your column div's.

You should do something like this:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <!-- content here -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <!-- content here -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <!-- content here -->
      </div>
    </div>
```